# Software solution for centralized server management

Tags: security

We operate around 20 servers, mostly running Debian. We are now planning a project migrating all servers to CentOS and reducing the amount of servers to save rack space. Being a virtual company (i.e. no office) we work with outsourced server admins, so it may be different admins doing work for us at different times.

What is the best practice to manage these servers for non-geek owners like us. Here are some of the things we'd like to centralize -- instead of logging into 20 different boxes and digging in config files:

- quickly check what version of what package/software is running on what box
- functionality to install new or update existing software package across the whole server farm
- give root access to outsourced tech on selected amount of boxes, then remove again once job is done
- check server uptime/load/bandwidth usage (optional)
- check firewall configuration across servers (optional)

Bar of hiring a full-time network admin, what's the next best software solution here?

Comment: Look at [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) and/or [mcollective](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/mcollective/index.html) and [func](https://fedorahosted.org/func/).  You can pay the consultants a bit of cash to set it up, and be in pretty good shape to review the output via the web UI.

Comment: Handling 20 servers by only part time people, and _no_ in-house expertise at all is very unwise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for two different products here.

- Configuration management
- Montoring/graphing

Both of those are large subjects, and shopping/product recommendation questions are a bit off topic here. So I'll give you a few links to get started because I think you're doing the right thing and want to encourage that, but you should do more research yourself. And maybe hire a linux guy, at least temporary, to help you with setting it up.

- [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com) and [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) are reasonably standard these days for linux config management
- [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) is the good old default for monitoring. There's also zabbix, multisite and others.
- [graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) is quickly gaining a lot of users, cacti and mrtg are also graphing solutions.

Comment: Don't forget the `nagios` fork `icinga`.  Love that web ui and reporting.

Comment: Also [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) for monitoring and graphing of local resources.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have taken your input, discussed it with a tech we hired for the job and settled on puppet for automation and RH spacewalk for package management. We'll use Zabbix for monitoring and graphs.